# Getting dynamic route url with Express JS causes favicon to disappear

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using express.Router(). Getting a dynamic route in the following way causes my favicon to disappear. (Where id is the dynamic part).

```
router.get('/collab/:id', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
```

Getting a non-dynamic route like this allows my favicon to load properly, all other things being equal.

```
router.get('/collab', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
```

Somehow in going from :id to the actual value, it forgets to include the favicon. Can't find similar questions using Google. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Is the favicon located under the `/collab` path as well? That's what appears to be the problem. You may benefit from using a dynamic regex path instead that only matches integers (or whatever) and allows other requests in a similar namespace to fall through to their designated handlers. Try something like: `/collab/:id(\d+)` if you are expecting integers

Comment: The favicon is down a /public path with the rest of my static assets.I don't understand your regex comment, but I tried your code just for fun but it broke the route.

Comment: Bummer. The regex comment was a guess predicated on the `/collab/:id` route being too greedy. If it's in a different namespace, that is probably not the case....

Comment: No matter what the value of id is, the next instruction is still just rendering the same view linking the same favicon, so that's why I don't see what the problem could be.